# How to give justify-content-center alignment to stackable columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want a responsive layout with x columns that shows 3 columns per row on `lg` screen sizes, `justify-content-between` aligned. The moment the screen is smaller than `lg`, all x columns should stack beneath each other, and they should be `justify-content-center` aligned.

I'm trying to accomplish this with one important thing in mind: the column divs surrounding the columns should be the exact same, so I can easily switch column 7 with column 3 without having to change something to the individual column divs.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-lg">
        <div style="width: 288px;" class="justify-content-center bg-primary">col 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg">
        <div style="width: 288px;" class="justify-content-center bg-secondary">col 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg">
        <div style="width: 288px;" class="justify-content-center bg-warning">col 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg">
        <div style="width: 288px;" class="justify-content-center bg-primary">col 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg">
        <div style="width: 288px;" class="justify-content-center bg-secondary">col 5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg">
        <div style="width: 288px;" class="justify-content-center bg-warning">col 6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/v9on4utk/).

As you can see, I have two main problems:

- Wrapping the columns in a `.col` breaks `justify-content-between`
- Column 4, 5 en 6 should automatically go to the next row.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you *need* to use Bootstrap? Is CSS Grid not an option?

Comment: I use it for other stuff on that page already so it's loaded anyway, but I guess a solution without bootstrap-stuff would work too if it's not possible with boostrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so if CSS Grid is an option this is what I came up with; pretty simple just defining the grid properties so only 3 columns are on each row, spaced between and they stack on top of each other using a simple media query which i set to the width of the **large** breakpoint from Bootstrap.

Let me know if this is like what you need!

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 288px);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  justify-content: space-between
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 288px;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like charm! Thanks!